# How to use pre-signed URLs for a private S3 bucket with Cloudflare?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

How can I make my S3 files private to public access and only make them accessible by using a pre-signed URL generated by the server, whilst using Cloudflare as a CDN? I made this work with Cloudfront but I'm not sure how to do it on Cloudflare.

The idea is to allow the user to only access the file by using a pre-signed URL, and if he tries to access the file directly it would need to say "Access denied".